# SQLAlchemy support for NOWAIT on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

MySQL has [recently](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3597) begun supporting NOWAIT for record-level update locking. This is very important for handling update contention, however I'm having difficulty trying to implement it in my web-app (SQLQAlchemy/Flask with MySQL database).

SQLAlchemy does not yet support this for the MySQL dialect (I use `pymysql`).

My specific SQL ORM expression reads:

```
line = cs.query(BookLine).filter_by(my_id).with_for_update(nowait=True, skip_locked=True)
```

and generates SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM bookline WHERE bookline.id = %(id_1)s FOR UPDATE
```

With that specific record locked by another session, this SQL will time-out and fail with unsatisfactory user experience. 
On command line, that SQL with `NOWAIT` appended fails instantly (correctly).

What the best way is to deal with this? Or is there support coming from SQLAlchemy (even on a patch basis)?

Options I see are:

1. Processing the raw SQL with addition, which is not very extensible to certain other contention situations I have.
2. Creating an alternative dialect with support for this feature (although I have no experience of that).
3. Patch existing dialect code, if that is a solution.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off filing an issue on the sqlalchemy repo? (assuming there isn't one already)

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, that is one of my next options. I'm also looking for advice in advance of any fix.